# WordPress deleting blog (posts) by itself

Tags: wordpress, malware, wordfence

I have a WordPress website. I have 27 posts/blogs there. but after some days it reduces itself to 20 and after sometime 15. I have to recover it using backup everytime it happens, it's really annoying.

There are a lot of user registered on my website but their role is set as "subscriber".
Only I have the admin access and I also have 2 Step Verification enabled using WordFence plugin. So If someone tries to login then I need to approve that IP.

Or is it a database problem?

Comment: Did you try "Activity Log" plugin?

Comment: I installed it just now

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by some plugin or your theme code. Check your plugins if there is something related to post expiration/pruning and also the `functions.php` file in your theme directory if there is some cron/schedule/remove filter. It certainly is not caused by the database itself.

Comment: I have checked my functions.php. Everything seems fine there

Comment: How do I know which plugin is causing the issue. I have 33 plugins installed

Comment: and it happens automatically so I have no idea when my posts are going to disappear

Comment: I'd search for keywords as expiration, expire, prune, pruning, remove, delete, cron, clean in the plugins list.

Comment: Couldn't find any plugin with these keywords.